# Nuxt.js Docs Website - How are the Code Embeds made?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I'm interested in how the Code Embeds with Copy to Clipboard at the Nuxt.js Documentation Website are made. Does somebody know if thes are component which can be installed through npm?

Or are they made by the next developers for showing on the site only?

[A Screenshot from the Nuxt Website which shows the specific Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikG5J.png)

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [code](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxtjs.org) on GitHub. They are using `@nuxt/content` for rendering markdown on their pages. In addition to that they use `tailwindcss` for the looks and `prismjs` for the code blocks. You can take a look on their [website](https://prismjs.com/) to see how to work with prism.

There are lots of guides how to setup nuxt with content and prism or even prism alone. I'm sure you'll find what fits best for you.